# Is the complement of a quadrant a manifold with corners?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

The definition of a manifold with corners is analogous to that of a smooth manifold, except that, instead of being  locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, is locally diffeomorphic to $[0,+\infty)^k\times \mathbb R^{n-k}$ where $0\leq k\leq n$.

The classical example is the quadrant $Q=[0,+\infty)^2\subset \mathbb R^2$, which has $(0,0)$ as corner point.

> Consider $X := \mathbb R^2 \setminus \mathrm{int}(Q).$ Is $X$ a manifold with corners?

The only problematic point is the origin which clearly has to be a corner point. We would like to show that a neighbourhood of the origin in $X$ is diffeomorphic to $Q$.

The naive idea would be to consider a map  $\varphi: X\to Q$, that informally  closes $X$ like a book so that it becomes $Q$.
This would give us an isotopy of $X$ over $Q$, but it does not seem to be a smooth map. Indeed, this isotopy at a certain time would also show that $X$ (and hence $Q$) is diffeomorphic to $[0,+\infty)\times \mathbb R$ which is a manifold with boundary (no corners).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the quadrant compliment is not a manifold with corners. Essentially, manifold corners have no notion of *angle* (i.e. smooth deformations may change the angles of a polygon), but they do have a notion of *convexity* (i.e. smooth deformations may not change a convex angle into a concave one).

To see this, note that there is no smooth curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to[0,\infty)^2$ with $\gamma(0)=0$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)\neq 0$. This property is local about the origin, and is preserved by smooth deformations, so it holds for *all* corner points of manifolds with corners. The origin in the quadrant complement $0\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(0,\infty)^2$ does *not* have this property, and is thus not a corner point.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! What I am left wondering is whether the complement of a quadrant is not a manifold with boundary (but no corners). That is, can there not be a boundary chart for that origin? A diffeomorphism from the upper half plane to the complement of the quadrant?

Comment: @horned-sphere The origin is not an ordinary boundary point either, by a similar argument. To be more systematic about it, you can look at the set of "extendible" tangent vectors$$E_p=\{v\in T_pM|\exists\  \text{smooth}\ \gamma:[0,\epsilon)\to M s.t. \dot{\gamma}(0)=v\}$$Since diffeomorphisms act on these subsets by linear transformation, they can distinguish various types of "corner points" in manifolds with corners. The origin in the quadrant compliment doesn't fit into any of these classes.

Comment: I don't know if that's what you had in mind, but I think the $E_p$ of the origin in the quadrant compliment and of a generic boundary point can be distinguished by the fact that the property $v\in E_p\Rightarrow -v\in E_p$ only applies to one vector, up to scaling in a boundary. Whereas for the origin in the quadrant complement it applies to infinitely many vectors.

Comment: @horned-sphere That argument works. More generally, in any number of dimensions $E_p$ for on a manifold with corners is always a convex set, whereas $E_0$ for the quadrant compliment is not convex.

Comment: How are you defining convexity exactly in your post? Because I think the upper half-plane is also convex so it doesn't distinguish it from the quadrant.

Comment: @horned-sphere What I mean to say is that $E_p$ is convex for *any* point in a manifold with corners; interior, boundary, or corner of any order. Since $E_0$ is not convex for the quadrant compliment, we can conclude that the quadrant compliment is not a manifold with corners.