# Are $\{ x\geq 0, y\geq 0\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ and $\{x\leq 0 \text { or } y\leq 0\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ diffeomorphic?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Consider the first quadrant $Q = [0,+\infty)\times [0,+\infty)\subset \mathbb R^2$ and the complement $X = \mathbb R^2\setminus \mathrm{int}(Q) = \{(x,y) \ |  x\leq 0\  \mathrm{ or } \ y\leq 0\}$.

Recall that a map $f:C\to \mathbb R^r$ defined on a closed subset  $C\subset \mathbb R^n$ is smooth if for any $x \in C$, exists  an open subset $U\subset \mathbb R^n$  and a smooth function $F:U\to \mathbb R^r$ such that $F|_{C\cap U} \equiv f|_{C\cap U}$.

> Question: are $Q$ and $X$ diffeomorphic?

Clearly the two are homeomorphic, the problem is the differentiability.
This question is motivated by my other question [Is the complement of a quadrant a manifold with corners?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4480979/is-the-complement-of-a-quadrant-a-manifold-with-corners)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not diffeomorphic. The manifold $X$ satisfies the following property:

> For every $x \in X$, there exists a smooth path in $X$ with nonvanishing derivative that passes through $x$.

For example, there is a smooth path in $X$ with nonvanishing derivative that passes through $x=(0,0)$, namely $\gamma(t)=(-t,t)$.

This property is invariant under diffeomorphism: if $X \subset \mathbb R^n$ is diffeomorphic to $Q \subset \mathbb R^m$, and if $X$ satisfies the above property, then so does $Q$.

However, $Q$ does not satisfy that property: for $q=(0,0)$ there does not exist any smooth path in $Q$ with nonvanishing derivative that passes through $q$. This can be proved using the [local immersion theorem](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekozai/m141f14/m141_notes.pdf).

Comment: This spurs a natural question: let $A_\theta$ be the portion of the plane enclosed by an angle $\theta$ with vertex at the origin, so that $Q=A_{\pi/2}$ and $X=A_{3\pi/2}$. This argument shows (I believe) that $A_\theta$ and $A_\eta$ are not diffeomorphic when $\theta<\pi\le\eta$. Are the remaining $A_\theta$ and $A_\eta$ all diffeomorphic (possibly requiring $\eta>\pi$ strictly)? Or are all the $A_\theta$ and $A_\eta$ mutually non-diffeomorphic?

Comment: All angles in $(0,\pi)$ are diffeomorphic: use a shear transformation to make the angle $\pi/2$. A similar method works for angles in $(\pi,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** it seems my argument fails at the origin, and so serves only to prove a diffeomorphism between $X-\{0\}$ and $Q-\{0\}$. In the comments OP links to an answer to a different question which claims that a diffeomorphism between $X$ and $Q$ is impossible.

View $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, then the complex function $f(z)=z^3$ maps $Q$ to the set $Y=\{x+i y\mid x\le0\;\textrm{or}\;y\ge 0\}$. If we then multiply by $i$ we rotate $Y$, transforming it into $X$. Therefore $g(z)=iz^3$ is a holomorphic function which maps $Q$ to $X$, which should be more than sufficient for proving a diffeomorphism.

Comment: This seems to be in contrast with the answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044891/is-there-any-diffeomorphism-from-a-to-b-that-fa-b
or am I missing something?

Comment: This is a very cool construction, but indeed there is a problem at the origin: The inverse „behaves morally“ like $z^{1/3}$, which is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain I think it would be very sensible to put this into the question. Also it seems that the argument in the answer there can be modified to answer your question here, no?

Comment: Ah, I guess my argument only works on the interior of these sets.

Comment: I think this answer is valuable  nonetheless (I upvoted it) because it completes the accepted answer below as it shows what would be a standard approach and why it fails.